# How to store dragged option element of a row between two different tables

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have two `tables` with different names generated by different ngFor loops.I used `cdkDrag` to drag them between diffenet lists.That works but my problem is when I set option on the dropdown and drag it to another list,it disappears as you can see below on the image

Below I updated the option from Audi to Saab(No problem here)

[image]

When I try to drag that row from `Done` list which has new `Saab` option to `ToDo` List, selected option disappears on the image below
[image]

Here my stackblitz example below.I'd be glad if you could help me

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save the selected option. E.g. add a property to your objects to store the option then bind to this from the select (property name in example is 'selected'):

```
<select id="cars" [(ngModel)]="feed.selected">
```

ts list: add to each object(:

```
 {name:"Example",num:2,char:"4",length:"5",difficulty:"easy", selected
: null},
{name:"Example1",num:2,char:"4",length:"5",difficulty:"easy", selected
: null}
//etc
```

As you loop the feed objects, it will bind each corresponding select to that property in the current object.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d-2ppc9e) based on yours.

Comment: Thanks for your help .But also I wanna ask something different.On the dragging state,last option also disappears here on the image you can see https://i.imgur.com/Vssh7jHl.png

Comment: Yeah that is a bit annoying, haven't found a way round it after a quick play about. It shows the default selected option during drag doesn't it.